# How to get clients Time zone

Tags: c#, silverlight

Im running into a lil problem here, i need to get the clients time zone off the browser since the time on his side that he specifies for scheduling is different to the server time. 
Its a silverlight application, and yeah cant really use javascript to try and get the timezone offset and save it as a cookie. Cant really use the culture info to grab the information to check which country they live in since some could have not set the browser language and still be using english-us so its not 100 perc correct. Have looked in to the timezoneinfo class but that seems to only give the time zone of the server and not the client.
Is there any way i can extract the time zone of the client without asking the user for it?

Thanks in advance,
Michelle

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to achieve the same thing. How did you solve this eventually?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone encounters this issue, DateTime.Now in Silverlight is client time. No need for JavaScript or other gimmicks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use TimeZoneInfo? See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.local%28VS.95%29.aspx).

EDIT: Nope. Disregard this, don't know why I missed this in the question. Without the use of javascript I can't think of a way to do this.

Comment: "The local time zone is the time zone on the computer where the code is executing." so nope i cant use that, i have gone through that already, its a silverlight web application the users will be all over the world accessing the site and putting in dates but this date will be different than the server date. Thats why i need their time zones :(